# Why can't I use the ternary operator inside a case in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a case statement and I am trying to use the ternary operator to do additional conditional checking.  But it errors out.

here is a sample of the code

```
case url
when partner_x_url then Rails.env.development? ? partner_signup_url : partner_signup_url :protocol => "https"
.
.
.
else regular_signup_url
end
```

The really weird thing is that it works if use the following

```
case url
when partner_x_url then if Rails.env.development?; partner_signup_url; else partner_signup_url :protocol => "https"; end
.
.
.
else regular_signup
end
```

Any ideas of why this is happening?

Comment: You may also consider extracting that to a method to keep the case statement more readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the `?` operator:

```
when partner_x_url then Rails.env.development? ? partner_signup_url : partner_signup_url :protocol => "https"
```

Happens to me all the time with a method ending in a question mark :)

**EDIT**: Since you now added that operator, I suspect it has to do with operator precedence. Try to avoid those kind of issues with using parentheses around function arguments:

```
when partner_x_url then Rails.env.development? ? partner_signup_url : partner_signup_url(:protocol => "https")
```

Example: Without function parentheses, you get a syntax error:

```
1.9.3p125 :006 > case @foo when true then true ? puts "foo" : puts "bar" end
SyntaxError: (irb):6: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
case @foo when true then true ? puts "foo" : puts "bar" end
                                      ^                                                ^
```

With parentheses, you don't:

```
1.9.3p125 :007 > case @foo when true then true ? puts("foo") : puts("bar") end
 => nil
```

Comment: Nope I have the ? mark in my code and it still errors out.

Comment: Not in your original code. If your edited code gives you an error, please add the error message to your question.

Comment: Hmm.. Interesting. The parenthesis did fix the problem.  So it must have been an ambiguity issue.